# Job timers not running

Tags: timer-jobs

Sorry I am new on sharepoint and haven't seen any fix using google.
I have sharepoint 2010 foundation and my timer jobs haven't ran for the last month or so. 
I tried to run the jobs manually but doesn't looks like it is running as the last run date doesn't change
The Sharepoint Timer service is running and I also restarted it.

**NOTE:** I think this may help, none of sharepoint jobs is running and the last date run is same on all of them which is one month ago.

Comment: Did you change the password of service account that is running SharePoint Timer Service?

Comment: Deploy the timer jobs again restart the timejob service and check running it manually again.

Comment: I believe our managed service changed the domain\administrator password... how can I see if this is a credentials issue?

Comment: I had this issue before. Try running the config wizard again. This seemed to fix the issue for me. Also, to check if it is a credential issue, you can open the properties of  SharePoint Timer service and check if credentials are valid.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? If so, please share, I am facing the same issue.